# Is it possible to detect if a div (class) exists between to others divs (classes)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is  possible to detect if a class exists ([Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery))

Is it possible to detect if a certain class exists between two other classes?

```
<div class="A"></div>

// if class B is not here - between anything with A follow directly by C, then put in B

<div class="C"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [+ selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)  in css. The below code will check if there is a C placed immediately after B and B placed immediately after A or not:

```
if ($('.A+.B+.C').length) {
  // Do something
} else {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check every `.A` element if its next neighbor not has class `B`. If so then add `<div class="B"></div>` in between.

jQuery

```js
$(".A").each(function() {
    var a = $(this),
        n = a.next("div");
    
    if (n.length && n.hasClass("B") === false) {
        a.after('<div class="B">B</div>');
    }
});
```

```css
.B { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="C">C</div>
<div class="A">A</div>
```

Vanilla JS

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".A")
        .forEach(a => {
            const n = a.nextElementSibling || { tagName: "" };
        
            if (n.tagName === "DIV" && n.classList.contains("B") === false) {
                a.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", '<div class="B">B</div>');
            }
        });
```

```css
.B { color: red }
```

```html
<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="C">C</div>
<div class="A">A</div>
```

Or if you know `.A` and `.C` then you could use the [adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to find all `.C` elements that are direct siblings of `.A`.

jQuery

```js
$(".A + .C").before('<div class="B">B</div>');
```

```css
.B { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="C">C</div>
<div class="A">A</div>
```

Vanilla JS

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".A + .C")
        .forEach(c => {
          c.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", '<div class="B">B</div>');
        });
```

```css
.B { color: red }
```

```html
<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="C">C</div>
<div class="A">A</div>
```